# Enable Bluetooth LE and scan for BLE devices

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

what's up !

In my latest project I'm using BLE device that exchanges simple data in BLE UART mode with my phone. I mostly know what activities I need to follow in my Android code in order to enable BLE device, scan area and connect with the appropriate BLE device (there are many examples on the net including [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#find) official).
When my Bluetooth on the phone is enabled, I can successfully scan the area and connect to the BLE device I want.
However, when I need to enable Bluetooth programmatically by using this code:

```
       if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
         Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
         startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
         }
        }
```

the scanning method finishes in the background during the time I'm enabling the Bluetooth. As a consequence, I'm unable to connect on my BLE device since there are no BLE devices found during the scan process.

As far as i understand, I should stop the main intent while enabling Bluetooth on the phone and continue the main intent once Bluetooth is enabled.

Can you give me a hint on how to do this: by using AsyncTask, another Thread or something similar ?

On the other hand, I have a particular BLE device with the particular name I want to connect to. How is it possible to make it that the app is constantly trying to connect with this BLE device keeping the app and the BLE device continuously connected. Do you have some useful code examples for me?

Thank you very much for your time and effort!

Sincerely,

Bojan.

Comment: As you call `startActivityForResult()` you should implement `onActivityResult()` to be informed when BT is enabled and then you can start the scanning. 

See: [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much Markus!!! And sorry for my Android ignorance.